# oracle stored procedure : variable is considered as *

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Please help, I was trying with an oracle procedure that takes as a parameter a variable then use it in SELECT INTO, The problem is the procedure doesn't consider this variable as one value.
This is a simple a code that explains what I mean.
ps : id_res is a primary key.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE annuler_res(id_res in number) 
 AS
 BEGIN
 UPDATE reservation SET etat_res='annulé' WHERE reservation.id_res= id_res;
 END;
```

This is my table before execution of the procedure 
[image]
When I execute it

```
 BEGIN 
 annuler_res(1);
 END;
```

And after execution all records are updated instead of one 
[image]

PS: I have created before this a procedure that in some how simulat an auto increment primary key.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the variable, Oracle is treating **id_res** as table column so your query becomes similar to a **WHERE 1=1**

Comment: I tried what you said, and it worked perfectly, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

You should *always* use aliases when calling SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE annuler_res(id_res in number) 
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE reservation SET etat_res='annulé' WHERE reservation.id_res= annuler_res.id_res;
END;
```

If you always use aliases, you will never encounter the issue where a PL/SQL variable name conflicts with the name of a table column.

Comment: Downvoted as such there is no Oracle documentation which says we should `ALWAYS` use `ALIASES` which calling SQL. Its always an Optional and ofcourse sometimes it bring some value when used. While answering you must specify why you should use Aliases

Comment: Still your comment is not elaborative as in why we should use aliases. You must tell how oracle deal with name resolution while parsing.